# Custom checkbox toggles attribute value

Tags: javascript, attributes, selector

I am trying to build a custom checkbox that adds or subtracts a value depending on if it is checked or not. ie: all checked boxes are summed.

```
$("div[active=1]").on("click",function(){
    var itemPrice = $(this).attr("itemprice");
    sum -= Number(itemPrice);
    $("#current_price").html(sum);
    $(this).attr("active","0");
});

$("div[active=0]").on("click",function(){
    var itemPrice = $(this).attr("itemprice");
    sum += Number(itemPrice);
    $("#current_price").html(sum);
    $(this).attr("active","1");
});
```

My issue is changing the boxes status as "checked" or unchecked". I'm using $(this).attr("checked",1); to change the status after the clicking.

Here is what I have so far, as you can see, a click on the 100 box (for example) just continues to ADD 100 as opposed to add/subtract/add/subtract....

http://jsfiddle.net/L76xzbLj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clickhandlers don't work for dynamically changed objects, try this instead:

```
$("body").on("click", "div[active=1]", function(){
    var itemPrice = $(this).attr("itemprice");
    sum -= Number(itemPrice);
    $("#current_price").html(sum);
    $(this).attr("active","0");
});

$("body").on("click", "div[active=0]", function(){
    var itemPrice = $(this).attr("itemprice");
    sum += Number(itemPrice);
    $("#current_price").html(sum);
    $(this).attr("active","1");
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L76xzbLj/7/

Comment: Figured that it was a problem with dynamic attribute. Thanks!